# TypeORM results to undefined on OneToOne relationship

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm new to NestJS (I had a bit of experience in Angular). I'm getting `undefined` when I console.log a JoinTable (the tables are new. I'm tasked to create a new microservice)

So `Unit` and `Hub` has `One to One` relationship.

Here is the unit

```
  @Entity({
    name: 'units',
  })
  export class UnitEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @OneToOne(() => HubEntity)
    @JoinColumn({name: "hub_id"})
    hub: HubEntity;
```

FYI I also tried coding it like this:

```
    @OneToOne(type => HubEntity, hub => hub.unit)
    @JoinColumn({name: "hub_id"})
    hub: HubEntity;
```

For the HUB:

```
 @Entity({
    name: 'hubs',
  })
  export class HubEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;
  
    @OneToOne(type => UnitEntity, unit => unit.hub)
    @JoinColumn({name: "hub_id"})
    unit: UnitEntity;
```

For testing, this is how I consoled it.

```
async findAllByUnit(unitId: number) {
    const unit = await this.unitRepository.findOne(unitId)

    console.log(unit.hub)
  }
```

It returns `undefined`

Please let me know what I'm missing.

Thank you in advance~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the relationship like this:

```
await this.unitRepository.findOne(unitId, {
    relations: ['hub']
})
```

Comment: hi! i stil get this error :( 
```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FindRelationsNotFoundError: Relation "hubs" was not found; please check if it is correct and really exists in your entity.```

Comment: Have you entered "hub" as singular in the relations array?

Comment: thank you! I finally got it. I missed this, and also removed the @JoinColumn in the hub entity. thank you!